# How to disable dates before today React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to disable dates that are before today so it can not be selected.
Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-calendar-r1h3b?file=/src/calendar.tsx

How can be it implemented?

Comment: Check `date` on `Day.onClick` before `setDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled the past dates here: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-calendar-1n9zk?file=/src/calendar.tsx:2706-2718

```
const Day = styled.div`
// ...

  ${props =>
      props.isPast &&
      css`
        color: #eee;
        pointer-events: none;
      `}

// ...
`
export function Calendar() {
// ...
             <Day
                key={index}
                isToday={d === today.getDate()}
                isPast={new Date(year, month, d) < today}
                isSelected={d === day}
                onClick={() => setDate(new Date(year, month, d))}
              >
                {d > 0 ? d : ''}
              </Day>
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this solution is that when you move next month the dates are still disabled for the next months.

Comment: You can check for June e.g.

Comment: `isPast={new Date(year, month, d) < today}`

Comment: This condition is working perfectly. I've edited the sandbox as well as my answer.